# How to cleanly validate function inputs and return a Future in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have a function (I removed the types because I'm more concerned about how to piece things together):

```
def func(opt1: Option, opt2: Option) = Future {
  for {
    o1 <- opt1
    o2 <- opt2
  } functionThatReturnsAFuture(o1, o2)
  Future.successful()
}
```

I'm trying to validate the options and then call my function that returns a future, but I don't know how to do this in idiomatic scala.

If I do this:

```
def func(opt1: Option, opt2: Option) = Future {
  for {
    o1 <- opt1
    o2 <- opt2
  } yield functionThatReturnsAFuture(o1, o2)
}
```

it's naturally going to return an Option[Future].

I could also do `opt1.flatMap(opt2.map(functionThatReturnsAFuture)).sequence` but this is still pretty ugly.

Is there any idiomatic scala (or scala + cats) way of doing validation like this and returning the Future?

Thanks!

Comment: Personally I would go for `getOrElse(Future.failed)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this using Scala elegantly. In any case you need to handle case in which one of the options is none or both of the options are none.

**Return failed Future in case one or both of the values are none.**

```
case class NoneFoundException(msg: String) extends Exception(msg)

def func(opt1: Option, opt2: Option) = {
 val result = 
  for {
    value1 <- opt1
    value2 <- opt2
  } yield someFutureReturningFunction(value1, value2)

 result.getOrElse {
  Future.failed(NoneFoundException("one or both of opt1, opt2 are none."))
 }

}
```

**Communicate with types instead of exceptions**

```
sealed trait Result[+A]

case class ReturnedValue[+A](value: A) extends Result[A]

case class NoneFound extends Result[Nothing]

 def func(opt1: Option, opt2: Option) = {
  val result = 
   for {
     o1 <- opt1
     o2 <- opt2
   } functionThatReturnsAFuture(o1, o2).map(value => ReturnedValue(value))

  result.getOrElse {
   NoneFound
  }

}
```

*Now the return type of the function is Future instead of Option of Future*